# Error en debug\AndroidManifest.xml ExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

Hoy estaba agregando las funciones de firebase desde el asistente y en el momento de hacer el *gradle build* me ha dado error en el archivo **debug\AndroidManifest.xml**, antes de agregar las funciones de firebase me compilaba sin problemas, adjunto el archivo **debug\AndroidManifest.xml** y los errores que me dan.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="15"
    android:targetSdkVersion="26" />

<br />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<br />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

<permission
    android:name="gerard.laxarxa.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="gerard.laxarxa.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:debuggable="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity android:name="gerard.laxarxa.account" />
    <activity android:name="gerard.laxarxa.register" />
    <activity
        android:name="gerard.laxarxa.login"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.VERSION"
        android:value="26.1.0" />

    <service
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService"
        android:exported="true" >
        <intent-filter android:priority="-500" >
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false" >
    </receiver>
    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementInstallReferrerReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false" />
    <service
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementJobService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.appinvite.PreviewActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppInvite.Preview" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.appinvite.ACTION_PREVIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiActivity"
        android:exported="false"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />

    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />

            <category android:name="gerard.laxarxa" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver"
        android:exported="false" />

    <service
        android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService"
        android:exported="true" >
        <intent-filter android:priority="-500" >
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <provider
        android:name="com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider"
        android:authorities="gerard.laxarxa.firebaseinitprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:initOrder="100" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.arch.lifecycle.VERSION"
        android:value="27.0.0-SNAPSHOT" />
</application>
```

> Error:(11) error: unknown element 
>  found.
>   Error:(15) error: unknown element 
>  found.
>   Error:(11) unknown element 
>  found.
>   Error:(15) unknown element 
>  found.
>   Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
>   Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
>   Error:com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
>   Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
>   Failed to execute aapt

Comment: Porque razón agregar <br /> ? ya probaste sin ellos, ya que no son reconocidos dentro de tu AndroidManifest.xml . El archivo AndroidManifest.xml de tu proyecto el cual dbes editar, es el que se encuentra dentro de  src\main\

Comment: Pero el problema es que yo no he editado ese archivo en ningún momento, no es el android manifest, sino que cada vez que me hace el gradle build se me abre un archivo que se llama debug\AndroidManifest.xml todo lleno de errores, y aunque lo edite arreglándolos al volver a hacer el gradle build vuelve a estar como al principio.

Comment: Ok, realizaste una actualización? @gery_08 de android Studio? Elimina todos los folder /build y su contenido en tu proyecto y vuelve a ejecutar el programa, dime que resultado tienes.

Comment: Si, me sigue dando error, pero por suerte el proyecto era bastante nuevo y no tenía demasiado hecho, he creado uno nuevo y no me hado error al agregar las dependencias, creo que copiaré lo que tengo hecho y trabajaré con ese. Gracias igualmente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error comentado, :

> Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for
>   details

implica que generalmente existe un problema en la configuración de tu proyecto, en este caso el problema visible es tu `AndroidManifest.xml`, no debes agregar     `<br />` , dentro de la configuración definida en el archivo.

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="15"
    android:targetSdkVersion="26" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/>

<permission
    android:name="gerard.laxarxa.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="gerard.laxarxa.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:debuggable="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity android:name="gerard.laxarxa.account" />
    <activity android:name="gerard.laxarxa.register" />
    <activity
        android:name="gerard.laxarxa.login"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.VERSION"
        android:value="26.1.0" />

    <service
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService"
        android:exported="true" >
        <intent-filter android:priority="-500" >
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false" >
    </receiver>
    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementInstallReferrerReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false" />
    <service
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementJobService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.appinvite.PreviewActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppInvite.Preview" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.appinvite.ACTION_PREVIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiActivity"
        android:exported="false"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />

    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />

            <category android:name="gerard.laxarxa" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver"
        android:exported="false" />

    <service
        android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService"
        android:exported="true" >
        <intent-filter android:priority="-500" >
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <provider
        android:name="com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider"
        android:authorities="gerard.laxarxa.firebaseinitprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:initOrder="100" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.arch.lifecycle.VERSION"
        android:value="27.0.0-SNAPSHOT" />
</application>
```

Es importante comentar que el archivo `AndroidManifest.xml` que debes editar en tu proyecto se debe encontrar dentro de la ruta `src\main\AndroidManifest.xml`.

Si eliges visualizar tu proyecto como "`Android`", aquí se encuentra tu `AndroidManifest.xml`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si eliges visualizar tu proyecto como "`Project`", aquí se encuentra tu `AndroidManifest.xml`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Pero el problema es que yo no he editado ese archivo en ningún momento, no es el android manifest, sino que cada vez que me hace el gradle build se me abre un archivo que se llama debug\AndroidManifest.xml todo lleno de errores, y aunque lo edite arreglándolos al volver a hacer el gradle build vuelve a estar como al principio.

Comment: @gery_08 comparte entonces tu configuración gradle, [editando tu pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/114071/edit) y colocándolo al final de la misma.

Answer (score 0):

El problema, [según esta respuesta de SO en Inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46948576/5587982), es que AAPT2 es más estricto al evaluar el archivo `Manifest`.

He tratado de ordenar tu archivo, [siguiendo la estructura indicada por Android](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html#filestruct), ya que por ejemplo, había algunas etiquetas `meta` que no estaban dentro de su elemento correspondiente.

De todos modos revísalo, no sea que haya puesto alguna etiqueta `meta` dentro de otro elemento... lo que he hecho ha sido ponerlas dentro del elemento precedente... suponiendo que pertenecían a él, pero estaban fuera.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="gerard.laxarxa.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<permission
    android:name="gerard.laxarxa.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="15"
    android:targetSdkVersion="26" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:debuggable="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity android:name="gerard.laxarxa.account" />
    <activity android:name="gerard.laxarxa.register" />
    <activity
        android:name="gerard.laxarxa.login"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.VERSION"
        android:value="26.1.0" />
    </activity>

    <service
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService"
        android:exported="true" >
        <intent-filter android:priority="-500" >
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false" >
    </receiver>

    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementInstallReferrerReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false" />

    <service
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementJobService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.appinvite.PreviewActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppInvite.Preview" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.appinvite.ACTION_PREVIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiActivity"
        android:exported="false"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />

    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />

            <category android:name="gerard.laxarxa" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver"
        android:exported="false" />

    <service
        android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService"
        android:exported="true" >
        <intent-filter android:priority="-500" >
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <provider
        android:name="com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider"
        android:authorities="gerard.laxarxa.firebaseinitprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:initOrder="100" > 

        <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <meta-data
        android:name="android.arch.lifecycle.VERSION"
        android:value="27.0.0-SNAPSHOT" />
       </provider>

</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Pero el problema es que yo no he editado ese archivo en ningún momento, no es el android manifest, sino que cada vez que me hace el gradle build se me abre un archivo que se llama debug\AndroidManifest.xml todo lleno de errores, y aunque lo edite arreglándolos al volver a hacer el gradle build vuelve a estar como al principio.