# Recibo este error: AAPT2 error: check logs for details

Tags: android, android-studio

estoy recibiendo este error! y realmente no sé que puede ser ya he probado varias cosas.

```
 AAPT2 error: check logs for details

Run tasks   2s 461ms
null    
resource android:style/TextAppearance.Material not found.   
resource android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Body1 not found. 
resource android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Body2 not found. 
resource android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Button not found.    
resource android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Caption not found.   
resource android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Display1 not found.  
resource android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Display2 not found.  
resource android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Display3 not found.  
resource android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Display4 not found.  
resource android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Headline not found.  
resource android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Inverse not found.   
resource android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Large not found. 
resource android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Large.Inverse not found. 
resource android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Large not 
found.  
resource android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Small not 
found.  
resource android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Medium not found.    
resource android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Medium.Inverse not found.    
resource android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Menu not found.  
resource android:style/TextAppearance.Material.SearchResult.Subtitle not 
found.
```

resource android:style/TextAppearance.Material.SearchResult.Title not found.

Manifiesto

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" >
</uses-feature>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.hkapps.dailyexpensemanager.DailyExpence"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_home"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.hkapps.dailyexpensemanager.Home"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_home"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.hkapps.dailyexpensemanager.Add_Expences"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_new_transaction"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.hkapps.dailyexpensemanager.History"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_history"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.hkapps.dailyexpensemanager.Settings"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_settings"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.hkapps.dailyexpensemanager.Edit_Category"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_edit__category"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.hkapps.dailyexpensemanager.History_List"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_history__list"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.hkapps.dailyexpensemanager.Edit_Expense"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_edit__expense"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.hkapps.dailyexpensemanager.Edit_Paymode"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_edit__paymode"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.hkapps.dailyexpensemanager.History_All"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_history__all"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.hkapps.dailyexpensemanager.ReminderActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_reminder"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.hkapps.dailyexpensemanager.MySimpleNotification"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_reminder"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.hkapps.dailyexpensemanager.TransactionNotification"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_reminder"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>

    <service android:name="com.hkapps.dailyexpensemanager.NotifyService" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.hkapps.dailyexpensemanager.HistoryByMonth"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_history_by_month"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.hkapps.dailyexpensemanager.HistoryMonthView"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_history_month_view"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>

  <activity
      tools:replace="android:configChanges"
      android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
      android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|uiMode|smallestScreenSize" />


    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

</application>
```

Grade

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


android {
compileSdkVersion 17
buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.hkapps.dailyexpensemanager"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 21
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
  'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
  }
}

dependencies {
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.+'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
implementation files('libs/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.jar')
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Mira el `AAPT2` es un complemento de optimización del `gradle` que no es compatible con el `framework Robolectric` y cuando se genera algún error recomiendan inhabilitarlo, para eso colocas `android.enableAapt2=false` en tu archivo `gradle.properties` te dejo las fuentes de donde obtuve la información

[build](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0)

[relase](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin)

También mencionan que el `AAPT2` es mas estricto con el archivo `AndroidManifest.xml` te dejo la fuente

[Manifest](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/114071/error-en-debug-androidmanifest-xml-executionexception-java-util-concurrent-exec)