# AAPT2 error: check logs for details 2018

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

Qué tal nuevamente amigos, estaba tratando de ejecutar un proyecto hasta que de pronto me salio el error AAPT2. He leído que para que desaparezca hay que resolver los errores desde lo ultimo. Y estos son los errores que me aparecen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No me marca error en ningún archivo, solo en el de "MainActivity.java" que es normal.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero no sé que estará causando conflicto, veo también que me dice que el archivo "values" esta con errores.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero no veo que me marque error, por eso he decidido compartirlo para ver que es lo que esta pasando.

Posdata, también comparto mi archivo "build.gradle(Module.app)"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: compa... tengo el mismo erro... ya pudiste solucionarlo....??? me urge... mil gracias

Answer (score 1):

Yo estaba usando de manera incorrecta un parámetro de Coordinator Layout, revisa tus layouts

```
app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="parent"
```

Era un atributo numérico, no literal, un muy tonto error

Answer (score 0):

mira el AAPT2 es un complemento de optimizacion del gradle que no es commpatible con el framework Robolectric y cuando se genera algun error recomiendan inhabilitarlo, para eso colocas `android.enableAapt2=false` en tu archivo `gradle.properties`
te dejo las fuentes de donde obtuve la información

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0
https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin

tambien mencionan que el AAPT2 es mas estricto con el archivo `AndroidManifest.xml` te dejo la fuente

[Error en debug\AndroidManifest.xml ExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/114071/error-en-debug-androidmanifest-xml-executionexception-java-util-concurrent-exec)

Comment: Hola @junior, lo del android.enableAapt2=false, ya me lo sabia pero igual da error la mayoria de veces.